# Iterating process of removing values in fields of shapefiles using ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iteration

I have a file geodatabase containing about 179 shapefiles.

In each of the shapefiles the attribute table in the fields (Ref: Picture), rows with same values are present which is identified from field, 'Shape_length'.

How do I carry out iteratively, delete identical for all of the shape files under database in ModelBuilder?

[Screenshot shapefiles within File geodatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsknd.jpg)

[image: Screenshot duplicate values in fields]

Answer (score 0):

(You dont have shapefiles you have a file geodatabase with feature classes in it)

1. Add a workspace variable, set it as a model parameter
2. Iterate Feature Classes with the wildcard `*PCS*` to only iterate over feature classes with PCS in the name
3. Delete Identical
   [image]